# how can I get message in nonblocked mode when using python redis subscribe

Tags: python, flask, redis

like below:

```
pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()

pubsub.subscribe("channel1") 

while True

        for msg in pubsub.getmessage():#nonblocked

              .....do something.....

        if other conditions are satisfied:

              break
```

My question is:
Is there any function like `getmessage()` as above to peek message?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! just use get_message() which works like select.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: pubsub = redis_client.pubsub()

pubsub.subscribe("channel1") 

while True

        while not pubsub.get_message():# nonblocked peek message until got one

             pass